# Cascading Windows context menu without disturbing default association?

Tags: windows, context-menu, file-association

I'm trying to create cascading context menus in Windows which will add new commands to specific filetypes without disturbing the default commands.

Here is an example:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\flv\shell\Cascade Menu]
"MUIVerb"="Remux"
"SubCommands"="remux to mkv;remux to mp4"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\remux to mkv]
"Icon"="\"C:\\Portable\\- Linked\\MKVToolNix\\mkvmerge.exe\""
@="remux to mkv"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\remux to mkv\command]
@="\C:\\Portable\\- Linked\\MKVToolNix\\Context Menu - remux to mkv.bat\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\remux to mp4]
"Icon"="\"C:\\Portable\\- Linked\\MKVToolNix\\mkvmerge.exe\""
@="remux to mp4"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\remux to mp4\command]
@="\C:\\Portable\\- Linked\\MKVToolNix\\Context Menu - remux to mp4.bat\" \"%1\""
```

Context Menu - remux to mkv.bat

```
cd %~p1

mkvmerge -o %~n1.mkv %1
```

Context Menu - remux to mp4.bat

```
cd %~p1

mkvmerge -o %~n1.mp4 %1
```

The menu displays properly but launching either of the options appears to do nothing.

If a command is changed to:

```
@="C:\\Portable\\- Linked\\MKVToolNix\\Conte...
```

Windows produces a dialog asking which application should be used to open the file.

How to configure so the command launches properly?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\remux to mp4\command]
@="\"C:\\Portable\\- Linked\\MKVToolNix\\Context Menu - remux to mp4.bat\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\remux to mkv\command]
@="\"C:\\Portable\\- Linked\\MKVToolNix\\Context Menu - remux to mkv.bat\" \"%1\""
```